# Fully ellastic collision of 2d ellipses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

I want to describe the behavior of two identical 2d ellipses with mass $m$ (rigid bodies), parametrized by $\phi_{a,b}(\alpha)=(a\cos(\alpha),b\sin(\alpha))$, after a fully ellastic collision without slippage. There major axis are not necessarily parallel, so a rotation is possibly applied to $\phi_{a,b}$. We assume that the mass is fully homogenously distributed in the ellipse, i.e., for any piece of the ellipse which contains the fraction $h$ of the area of the ellipse, the mass contained in it is $m h$ .

Assuming, that ellipse $A$ is rotated at time of collision by $U_A$, has a velocity vector $v_A$ and the center of mass at $x_A$, and ellipse $B$ has the properties $U_B$, $v_B$ and $x_B$. From those we can calculate the contact point $p$. I am now wondering whether the collision would rotate the ellipses or not. It seems "intuitive" that if $p$ lies on the extension of both major or both minor axis, that then no rotation happens, but in any other case I should see rotation (at least if I let two ellipses slide on my floor). Or is the assumption that there is no slippage avoiding this possibility?